# crossing if statement function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

I am trying to make an if statement that only goes through when the green line is crossed by the black line or if the red line crosses the black line. Note that the green and red line values are not equivalent to black_line values so i cannot use the <=, >= or == functions when defining the if statement.

```
black_line = [*black line values]
green_line = [*green line values]
red_line = [*red line values]
for i in range(len(black_line)):
    if green_line [i] crosses black_line[i]:   
        print("green line crossed")
    elif red_line [i] crosses black_line[i]:   
        print("red line crossed")
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by " green and red line values are not equivalent to black_line values", can you please add some sample values in your question?

Comment: Can you bring more precisions on the structure of your data ? Showing us how you plot it should be enough

Comment: Can you think of a mathematical rule, in terms of the current *and previous* sample values for the lines, that tells you whether a crossing occurred? Hint: think about the *difference between* the samples before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines have crossed if the previous value of one line was lower than that of the other line and the current value is not lower, or vice versa.

```
for i in range(1:len(black_line)):
    prev_black = black_line[i-1]
    cur_black = black_line[i]
    prev_green = green_line[i-1]
    cur_green = green_line[i]
    prev_red = red_line[i-1]
    cur_red = red_line[i]

    if prev_black < prev_green != cur_black < cur_green:
        print("green line crossed")
    if prev_black < prev_red != cur_black < cur_red:
        print("red line crossed")
```